# is ye a subject or object or either, and can it be before or after or either?

Tags: grammar, old-english

Is Ye a subject, or an object, or either?

And would it go before a verb, or after a verb, or either?

For example

> Seek Ye

A) is 'Seek Ye' valid. 
B) if so, is Ye the subject,  as in, you(plural) should seek ____  Or is it the object, as in  Seek you(plural) , as in, seek yourselves

> Ye Seek

A) Is 'Ye Seek' valid?
B) you(plural) seek, or should seek, but without specifying what. Without specifying the object.

Is "Yee seek the table", the same as "seek ye, the table"?

I'm confused about subject and object and the position of ye before or after the verb.. i'm interested in knowing all the possibilities.   which are valid and invalid and what they mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ye* or *ȝe* is or was a [nominative second person plural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye_%28pronoun%29), so it was used in Middle and Early Modern English to denote subjects and subject complements. So *seek ye* should mean "you should seek", and *ye seek* "you seek". As to whether the word *seek* is used in the proper way and form in those example, I do not know.

Comment: *Informal* second person, the plural complement of "thou"?

Comment: @SpencerSimpson: There was no formality distinction in the second-person plural pronouns.

Comment: @sumelic  did he say there was?